# pandas dataframe slicing produce different results

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I am trying to do a bandpass filter on accelerometer data by passing data frame slices to my function, but I am getting different results based on the way I am slicing my data

I tried to used column names and index using `iloc` but the results are different, so I do not which results are the correct results

my band pass filter function:

```
def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=6):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
    return b, a


def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs):
    b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=6)
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y
```

and below the two ways, I used to pass my data to the function:
first way : using `tremor_0[['X']] as [[]]` slicing for column name

```
y=pd.DataFrame(data=butter_bandpass_filter(tremor_0[['X']],0.3,12,100),columns=['X'])
```

the second way :
using `tremor_0['X'] as []` slicing for column name

```
y=pd.DataFrame(data=butter_bandpass_filter(tremor_0['X'],0.3,12,100),columns=['X'])
```

results from first way:

```
    X
0   -0.001962
1   -0.001962
2   -0.001948
3   -0.001903
4   -0.001874
```

results from second way:

```
    X
0   -0.001962
1   -0.019822
2   -0.095867
3   -0.298136
4   -0.675933
```

notice that starting from the second row the values are different, so which way is the correct way and why, please?

[screenshot of my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmZip.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide [minimal example to produce the error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Remember the community members are volunteers, a question which takes some time (and effort to understand) or is incomplete will discourage people from answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: use `tremor_0['X']`.

**Long answer**

First of all, `tremor_0[['X']]` and `tremor_0['X']` are not the same.

Suppose if you have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.ndarray((100, 10)), columns=['x_%i' % i for i in range(10)])
type(df[['x_0']])
# pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
type(df['x_0'])
# pandas.core.series.Series
```

More importantly, they have **different shape**

```
df[['x_0']].shape
# (100, 1)
df['x_0'].shape
# (100, )
```

which `scipy.signal.lfilter` handles differently, since it applies filter to `axis=-1`.

> **axis : int, optional**
>   The axis of the input data array along which to apply the linear filter. The filter is applied to each subarray along this axis. Default is -1.

If you change your `lfilter` argument to `axis = 0`, `butter_bandpass_filter` returns array with sample values. But keep in mind that the resulting array will follow the shape of input.

Comment: thank you for your response , what if I would like to pass dataframe with three columns? is it better to pass it tremor_0_filterd=pd.DataFrame(data=butter_bandpass_filter(tremor_0[['X','Y','Z']],0.3,12,100),columns=['X','Y','Z'])?

Comment: @GhaythMahadin better than what, if I may ask?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `tremor_0[['X']]` you get back a dataframe object, which is an array.  When you use `tremor_0['X']` you get a Series object which can be easily converted to a list

If you are just trying to extract data from a 1 dimensional column then use `tremor_0['X']` but you should verify what result makes sense given the data and what you are trying to achieve